# PHP file_get_contents and curl get a result but also no result

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, google-finance

I have the following code:

```
$url='http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:GOOG';
$quote = file_get_contents($url);
echo $quote . "<br>";
```

which returns a result.

but

```
$url='http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=FTSE:BBY';
$quote = file_get_contents($url);
echo $quote . "<br>";
```

does NOT return a result. Instead it returns nothing.

Both URLs work in Firefox and provide a page source ok.

I have tried to get the contents using CURL and still cannot get the data from the `FTSE:BBY` or other `FTSE:?????` sources.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure both url's work? The second url doesn't work in my browser (FireFox).

Comment: OK,  I have found out what it is.  Code for FTSE should be LON e.g. LON:BBY.  I tried FTSE, LSE and both return code using firefox, but only LON for London Stock Exchange will return code using php script.  Anyway it has only taken me all day to fix this.  Feel stupid now.....